# Indexing IQueryable<int>?

Tags: c#, linq

How do you index an IQueryable?

I am using a LINQ to sql query to get in values from a particular column. The query is as follows,

```
var intitalQuery =  (from a in sql.GetTable<Staff_Time_TBL>()
                                where a.Info_Data == SelectedOption
                                select a.Staff_No).Distinct();
```

From there I want to be able index the `intitalQuery` variable and get values as needed.
That value is then used in another query. 
My first try was this,

```
  Column1.DataContext = sql.Staff_Time_TBLs.Where(item =>                     
                     item.Section_Data == SelectedOption &&
                     item.Staff_No == intitalQuery[0];
```

Then I tried this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293263/convert-iqueryableint-to-int) with no luck.

```
Column1.DataContext = sql.Staff_Time_TBLs.Where(item =>
                     item.Section_Data == SelectedOption &&
                     item.Staff_No == intitalQuery.First());
```

From what I can from the link is that that way gets just the first value, I want to be able to get all values via indexing. How do you go about that?

Comment: `.ToList()`? Otherwise I'm not quite sure what you mean by "indexing", and why you would even need it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, Loop through the `intitalQuery` via a `for loop`, not `foreach` loop.

Comment: @JeroenMostert. Thanks , that worked. If you want to post the answer I will mark it as solved. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`IQueryable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb351562) inherits from `IEnumerable` and as such has a wealth of extension methods to accomplish almost anything you'd need from a sequence. In particular, [`.ToList()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb342261) turns an enumerable into a `List<T>` that allows efficient indexing.

`.ToList()` is slightly more efficient than the more obvious `.ToArray()` when working with sequences of unknown initial length, because `.ToArray()` requires an additional copy to end up with an array of exactly the right size. (But arrays are faster to loop over, so it all depends on what you're doing.)

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
 public static List<Staff_Time_TBLs> GetIndexed(string staffNo){
   var stuff  =    sql.Staff_Time_TBLs.Where(item =>                     
                 item.Section_Data == SelectedOption &&
                 item.Staff_No == staffNo;
   return stuff.ToList();
 }

 //to use it...
 initialQuery.ForEach(p=>{ 
     var indexvalue = GetIndexed(p)
 });
```